# Group ruby array in rails by year and month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently sort my events like;

```
@events_by_month = @events.group_by { |x| x.date.month }
```

this relied on the fact that all events occurred in the same year, however I now want to show events from next year too.
I'd like the output in the same format as what the above outputs but sorted by year i.e
this is what I have;

`{3=>[#<Event id: 7032, date: "2014-03-02 00:00:00">, #<Event id: 7033, date: "2015-03-02 00:00:00">]}`

and this is what I'd like;

`{3=>[#<Event id: 7032, date: "2014-03-02 00:00:00">]},{3=> [#<Event id: 7033, date: "2015-03-02 00:00:00">]}`

Comment: the expected output is an array of hashes with a single element having the month as key? looks very weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to group events by month and year as I understood.
Then use
`@events_by_month = @events.group_by { |x| [x.date.month, x.date.year] }`
you'll receive

```
{[3, 2014]=>[#<Event id: 7032, date: "2014-03-02 00:00:00">]},{[3,2015]=> [#<Event id: 7033, date: "2015-03-02 00:00:00">]}
```

It will be more correct then duplicated keys in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you

```
results = []

@events.group_by { |x| x.date.year }.sort.
  each { |_, e| results << e.group_by { |x| x.date.month } }
```

example

```
[
  #<Event:0x007fd957d3dd98 @date=2014-03-02 21:37:18 +0200>,
  #<Event:0x007fd957d6e9e8 @date=2014-01-01 00:00:00 +0200>,
  #<Event:0x007fd957da4228 @date=2014-03-01 17:52:12 +0200>,
  #<Event:0x007fd957db98f8 @date=33702-11-27 23:25:40 +0200>
]
```

will give

```
[
  {
    3=>[#<Event:0x007fd957d3dd98 @date=2014-03-02 21:37:18 +0200>,
        #<Event:0x007fd957da4228 @date=2014-03-01 17:52:12 +0200>],
    1=>[#<Event:0x007fd957d6e9e8 @date=2014-01-01 00:00:00 +0200>]
  },
  {
    11=>[#<Event:0x007fd957db98f8 @date=33702-11-27 23:25:40 +0200>]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that events are sorted (`sort_by(&:date)`):

```
@events.group_by { |e| e.date.year } \
       .values \
       .map { |es| 
         es.group_by { |e| e.date.month } 
       }
```